# Python app move to Apache WSGI - enabling Multi-Process

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am new to Python, have experience with serves and apache in general. And so, I am working with this Python-based application, web parser, I guess. It's using `Flask` with its builtin webserver `Werkzeug`... while on a VPS it worked great as is, but moving to a multi-process (+ multi-thread) dedicated server I've run into problems.

*First of all* it's the message from Flask to move to a production WSGI server and drop `Werkzeug`...

*And second*, the program refused to start with more than 1 process (can have a number of processes as a parameter), saying that I cannot have both multi-threaded and multi-process environments (with `Werkzeug`, right?)... I was able to start the app with 1 process as a parameter, and **it would work and only use 1 process**, and eventually start lagging from too many requests...

And so, I've read a few articles and tried to do the move to apache WSGI. as instructed, I did the following steps...

**created a folder** `/var/www/app-server`, then created `APPNAME.wsgi` file with following code and placed it in that folder:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/app-server')
from APPNAME.server import app as application
```

**went to apache config** and added the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:9192>
    ServerName server.name

    WSGIDaemonProcess APPNAME user=apache group=apache threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/app-server/APPNAME.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/app-server>
        WSGIProcessGroup APPNAME
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**saved and restarted apache**, added firewall port, etc..

So, now NOTHING basically has changed, and although it is working, **it is still using only 1 process**, although now I don't need to tell it to do so via parameters... and of course now it's the `httpd` process. same everything as before, just 1 process under "different name".

I am very lost now, didn't I do things correctly? Or is there another piece of software needed in-between Python app and apache, like `gunicorn` or something?

So, this wasn't a good solution for me, and I ended up going into the Python source code for the app and explicitly told it not to use threads on `app.start` I gave it `threaded=False` parameter. Now, it is working, as the original app, and using its original web server, and using multiple processes.

The WSGI file refers to the same code and same app, and still, even with multi-process enabled in the app, it is only using 1 `httpd` process as before.

Please, anyone with advice on how to make my WSGI app use more than 1 `httpd` process? Even right now in the downtime the app is using 24 processes and keeping the server at 40% CPU usage (8 cores, 8 threads). top shows all 8 cores being busy. So, the app puts some strain on the server, but barely uses any RAM, mostly its CPU power... So, in heavy traffic times, it actually overloads the server...

Could it be the user and group of the app that it runs under? Does it have to be same group as listed in the `WSGIProcessGroup`?

Comment: You are using one process with 5 threads, so it can handle more than one request at a time unless the way your code works it blocks on multiple threads for some reason, or is CPU intensive and therefore encounters GIL conflicts. If you want more than one process, use ``processes=3 threads=3``. Suggest you read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/processes-and-threading.html and http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html

Comment: ok i got it, thanks, this is, of course, not a double for that Django question, but yes, the answer will be adding processes=N right next where threads=N is set. i actually thought those were settings per process, and that apache would handle it from there... and i already am seeing decrease in load on the server, nice!! apache is way better than Werkzeug...

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton if you want to answer with "Add 'processes=N' there etc " i will accept that answer.. =) although i am not sure now, should i go back into that python source and remove threads=no that i added there? or will it stop working.. i gotta test, i guess..

Comment: The ``threads`` option defaults to 15. Better off dropping the number when going multiple process anyway.

Comment: so if it needs more than 15 threads, will it use them? need to make sure my [facebook video downloader](https://4fb.site/) doesnt run out of resources. now it uses heroku but time to move python app to my own server

Comment: The amount of threads per process is fixed. No autoscaling as that is actually somewhat dangerous. If you are you doing long running downloads you probably don't want to be routing all the data through a WSGI application. Offload transfer to a web server, or use an async based application.